# Avoid Mercurial adding Local/Other tags to original file when merging

Tags: merge, mercurial, beyondcompare

I am using mercurial via tortoiseHg (windows) as a source control management tool.

I am used to merge using beyond a compare. Today, I have to perform a very complex merge and I just discovered a new feature (my client was updated some days ago) that is extremely annoying.

When I have a conflit and ask Mercurial to take the "other" file and keep the original in a .orig file, the .orig is added with <<<<<<< local and >>>>>>> other, but more than this, the other part is merged into the original one !!!

The two parts are then unaligned and it's impossible to guarantee that the merge is OK because you have to review it line by line with no help from the comparision tool. (see screen below).

http://s13.postimg.org/yor6gno47/Untitled.jpg

I want to disable this feature, but so far, I am unable to do it. Thanks so much for help as this is furthermore blocking my work.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The launching of a specific merge tool isn't something Mercurial controls.   It does, however, have a robust mechanism for [Merge Tool Configuration](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) that allows you to provide a preference order and it will use the first one it can find.  The builders of various Mercurial installation packages (ubuntu, etc.) and tools that include Mercurial (TortoiseHG, etc.) all provide their own Merge tool configuration preference list.

Either the old merge tool configuration list you had not longer points to Beyond Compare at the right location (upgraded BC and the directory name changed, etc.) or you got a new merge tool configuration list when you updated some software that included mercurial.  Either way that page on MergeToolConfiguration will help you find your preference list in your hgrc files and update or correct it.

Tl;Dr: this isn't a "new" feature it's your new installation being less tailored for your system than your old one.  Maybe find who packaged that one and copy the merge tool config.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

Actually, it is the default installation of the latest TortoiseHg pack. The mercurial.ini file did not change. I removed the $local and $other arguments for BYC2 from the [merge-tools] entry but it's still merging that way.

I've notice the new <<<<<<< local and >>>>>>> other entries since some months, but it was still aligned. Reverting to tortoise 2.3 revision solves my problem. But I'd like to use the most recent one.

Thanks.

Comment: I just done the latest package installation again, same behavior, no mercurial.ini changes, no repositories changes.

This is very frustrating as little changes are now completly lost in a big 50 lines long BYC2 difference in front of ... nothing.

Comment: Right.  TortoiseHG is not from the Mercurial project.  They repackage Mercurial and extensively modify the system-wide configuration files.  They either excluded beyond compare this time or are included it in but are pointing to a different place.  Find their old config and make your merge tool configuration match, but it wasn't Mercurial that did this to you; it was TortoiseHG.